# Что делать, если is not a supported wheel on this platform при установке?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

Пытаюсь установить `tensorflow` на Windows, Python 3.5

В консоли:

```
C:\Users\Администратор\pip install --upgrade httpd://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Какая разрядность (32, 64) у ОС и у интерпретатора? Должна быть в обоих случаях 64

Comment: Да, разрядность системы - 64, пайтона - 32. По поводу замечаний по оформлению - учту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вкратце: разрядность ОС и Python должна совпадать - в данном случае в обоих случаях - 64.

---

`Wheel` - специальный формат для установки пакетов. Он представляет из себя простой ZIP архив с необходимыми файлами, при этом по сути из установки исключена стадия сборки. Например, при установке колеса нет нужды компилировать [расширения Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html) (.pyd, .so), которые включены в некоторые пакеты, работающие с низкоуровневым кодом на C. Например, `numpy`, `scipy`, `tensorflow`. Компилировать не нужно, потому что скомпилированные файлы уже включены в архив и вам (установщику пакетов) нужно только распаковать файлы и положить в нужную папку. Так как скомпилированные файлы имеют разный формат для как минимум разных ОС собирают разные колеса. Ориентироваться можно по имени - `win` в имени говорит, что колесо собрали для специально для Windows и на других ОС работать не будет. Также вы должны соблюдать разрядность как ОС, так и самого интерпретатора - если колесо собрано для 64 (`amd64` в названии), то ОС и интерпретатор должны быть такой же разрядности. Не все пакеты, тем не менее, разделяются по разрядности и ОС - многие написаны на голом Python и без разницы куда устанавливаться.