# Как установить lxml в виртуальное окружение PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, lxml

У меня:
Python 3.8.1
Windows 10 - 64

На PyCharm'е в виртуальное окружение пытаюсь поставить lxml:

```
(venv) F:\testProjekt\Fs_h>pip install lxml
```

Получаю в конце примерно следующее:

```
 running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "F:\testProjekt\Fs_h\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\popkov\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mcl3hk8o\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read(
).replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\popkov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4b6h6qyg\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers F:\te
stProjekt\Fs_h\venv\include\site\python3.8\lxml" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\popkov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mcl3hk8o\lxml\
```

По ссылке из ошибки открывается страница для скачивания каких то студий, никогда ими не пользовался, но одна установлена зачем то, в общем глобально(не в окружение) lxml нормально ставится(сюда "C:\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml") я даже пользовался ничего не обычного работает, а в окружение никак(

Вопрос у меня следующий:
Как мне еще можно поставить lxml именно в окружение? Может вручню что докинуть или еще какой установщик попробовать?

Дополнительная информация:

На одном форуме посоветовали установить wheel от сюда [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) .

Пытался ставить несколько штук, ради эксперимента и 32х пробовал, но ответ всегда был один:

```
(venv) F:\testProjekt\Fs_h>pip install lxml-4.4.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
lxml-4.4.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: lxml основан на одноименное бинарной библиотеке. Для ее компиляции требуется набор компиляторов и библиотек. Именно это вам и предлагают скачать и установить - "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools". Можете смело качать и ставить.

Comment: По поводу `wheel` могли бы хотя бы погуглить. Есть же ответ [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657358/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5) и [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку у меня lxml нормально ставился в глобальную site-pakages, но не ставился в окружение, я просто перекинул два каталога lxml  в ..\venv\Lib\site-packages, может так делать и не правильно, но проблема решилась.